# Disable sending a copy to sender in contact form Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a static website with a contact form developed using drupal 7. When a user enters an email address, name, subject, and text, a copy is automatically sent to the sender. How do I disable this feature in the code side? I couldn't find this feature on the admin side in drupal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
By default there is one checkbox called 'Send yourself a copy' is on contact form which is by default unchecked. As i can see it is not visible in attached screenshot. Maybe it hidden because of captcha.

Or else we can alter form using hook_form_alter on .module file and add following code.
if ($form['#form_id'] == 'contact_site_form') {
$form['copy']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```